# How to inline elements inside input-group (Force them to be on one line)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to inline the elements inside my div without breaking them down into their own col

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-12">
   <label for="null" class="control-label">Item Add-ons</label>
 </div>

 <div class="items_part">

    <div class="col-xs-12">
       <div class="input-group added_items">
           <input type="text" name="item_name[]" value="Ticket" class="form-control" readonly="">
           <input type="text" name="item_desc[]" value="Free Ticket" class="form-control">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove input-group-addon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This ends up with the inputs taking up a 100% width thus they end up stacked up against each other.

To make it more clear I want to have this as:

```
input1 input2 delete_button
```

This code results in:

```
input1
input2
delete_button
```

Also a link to the inline form of bootstrap: [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-inline)

Comment: Comments for the downvote? My question is pretty clear and I'm not an expert in CSS as well. If you could also explain your vote to close that would be great so that I can add information to this question that you believe is lacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-12">
   <label for="null" class="control-label">Item Add-ons</label>
 </div>

 <div class="items_part">

    <div class="col-xs-12">
       <div class="input-group added_items">
```

```
          <li> <input type="text" name="item_desc[]" value="Free Ticket" class="form-control"></li>
          <li>  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove input-group-addon" aria-hidden="true"></span></li>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css: added_items{width:100%;}
     added_items ul li{display:inline-block; width:30%;}